# PowerShell: ErrorAction set to "SilentlyContinue" not working

Tags: powershell, error-handling

The following command does *not* show the error message, which *is* what I want:

```
Copy-Item "C:\Folder I Have Access To\*" "C:\Folder I Do Not Have Access To" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The following command *does* show the error message, which is *not* what I want:

```
Copy-Item "C:\Folder I Have Access To\*" "C:\Folder I Do Not Have Access To" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This is because I'm using the "Force" parameter. Is there a way I can use the "Force" parameter and still not show the error message?

Comment: any final solution about it with full source code sample?

Answer (score 11):

Add this first.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
```

Comment: This may need to be set in addition to a try catch due to objects (outside of your code) having exceptions being thrown back at your session. By setting the global preference, you also silence these errors being reported to screen.

Comment: Excellent comment, @RagingCain!!  This was driving me nuts.

Comment: Worked well for me too, great stuff.

Comment: Note that this sets the ErrorAction preference for all future calls as well.  If you only want this set for one call (or a small handful of calls), then you need to set it back to whatever it was before.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Just for that powershell session? Or all future sessions?

Comment: @johnywhy Just for that session

Answer (score 6):

Can you try this :

```
trap
{
  continue
}
Copy-Item "C:\Folder I Have Access To\*" "C:\Folder I Do Not Have Access To" -Force -errorAction SilentlyContinue
```

or

```
try
{
  Copy-Item "C:\Folder I Have Access To\*" "C:\Folder I Do Not Have Access To" -Force -errorAction SilentlyContinue
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to run across your post as I was searching for an answer to mine. This post seems to resolve to it being a bug, although this one is talking about the "Verbose" parameter, it could apply to -force as well.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b76eccae-4484-43ec-a3dc-d4bc581124c2/adding-verbose-to-a-cmdlet-prevents-script-from-terminating-on-error?forum=winserverpowershell